# How to use angularJs for dynamically created HTML(Which is not loaded to DOM)

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hello I am very new to AngularJs. 
I am retrieving the HTML data from C# by calling ajax function. Here i am trying to use the AngularJs functionality for the dynamically generated HTML. But i am not able to see any AngularJs effect on this.But AngularJs effect is working fine for static HTML.Please help me on this.

Below is the example.

**C# Code:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string DynamicHtml()
{
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("    
                       <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
                           <h1 id='myName' ng-click='changeName()'>
                              {{firstname}}
                           </h1>
                        </div>
           "); 

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

**HTML Code:** myPage.aspx

```
<html>
  <head>

      <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready({

     $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          content-type:'application/json;charset-4',
          url:'myPage.aspx/DynamicHtml' 
          success:function(data){

               $("#div1").html(data.d);

               ChangeNameFunc();
                 } 
          })


        function ChangeNameFunc()
        {
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.firstname = "John";
            $scope.changeName = function () {
            $scope.firstname = "Nelly";
        }
    });
  }

});
```

In the above code i am retrieving the html data from c# by using ajax call and binding it to **div1**. When i try to click on John the name is not changing to Nelly. Please note that Angular function worked when used in static page.

Comment: You must initialize ng-app and import library file in the static DOM. Then you can add any dynamic code to it. Sometimes you need to q.apply() the code to refresh the angular DOM.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please try declaring the **ng-app** and **ng-controller** in the  itself and let me know.

Comment: Hi Alexis thanks for the reply. There are multiple ng-app i am using. So i wanted to generate everything dynamically. Please provide me the other way.

Comment: For my suggestion better do nor use multiple ng-app's

Comment: But in case if we don't have any option then how can we achieve. Please help me out